# Adding hyphens in Crystal Report Expressions

Tags: crystal-reports

I am not too familiar with Crystal and I have been tasked with modifying a report. There is an if then else expression that displays a department number based on a certain value. For example...

```
If {@Team} = 8013 then 51 else
If {@Team} = 8014 then 34 else
If {@Team} = 8016 then 48 else...
```

I need to change those values to a set of new department codes, so the following should look something like this...

```
If {@Team} = 8013 then 001-00 else
If {@Team} = 8014 then 001-21 else
If {@Team} = 8016 then 001-01 else...
```

However, the output is treating those numbers like an equation and outputting a difference. How can I display the hyphenated numbers in the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn them into strings, with our good friend the quotation mark:

```
If {@Team} = 8013 then "001-00" else
If {@Team} = 8014 then "001-21" else
If {@Team} = 8016 then "001-01" else...
```

Comment: Dang. You know, I didn't think the double quotes were working because I was only trying them on a few lines just to see if it would work. I didn't realize I had to add them to all 63 lines in order to avoid error messages. I should have tried that in the first place. Many thanks!